# Is Pad See Lew the same as Pad See Ew?

Tags: thai-cuisine

I have been looking across the Internet to see if these two Thai dishes (Pad See Lew and [Pad See Ew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad_see_ew)) are the same. I believe that they are and that they are just spelled different in different regions (possibly). But I’m not sure so I thought I’d ask for some seasoned advice.

Pad See Ew is sometimes spelled Pad Siew, Pad Siu or Phat Si-Io.

Comment: Where did you encounter "Pad See Lew"?  Are you sure it's not just a typo?

Comment: I just ordered it this evening at a local Thai restaurant.

Comment: Might still be a typo on the menu ;-) happens all the time.

Comment: I think that's the question @Johannes_B.

Comment: I looked at other menus online (from other Thai restaurants) and I see both spellings (not on the same menu, of course).  I am leaning to the idea that it’s the same dish but there are two spellings.

Comment: I edited your question to include a link to the Wikipedia article for Pad See Ew. FWIW, when I typed "pad see lew" into wikipedia, it immediately re-routed me to the article for pad see ew. It's not definitive, but that seems to point towards them being the same thing spelled differently.

Comment: @csk Thx.  Good point - I am leaning to the idea that these two spellings are for the same dish.

Comment: Pad siew = pad si ew. Never heard of the other two.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I'm leaning into "Pad See Lew" being a pure typo.  Listen to Pailin pronounce it here: https://hot-thai-kitchen.com/pad-see-ew-new/  You'll hear there there's not even a hint of an "L" sound.  Pad See Ew, Pad Sieu, Pad Seuwe, etc. are all fair transliterations, but not "Lew".

Comment: Maybe it’s named after a guy named Lew who works at the restaurant.

Comment: Suffice it to say that all these spellings refer to the same dish.  I called the manager at a local Thai restaurant here in the Dallas Texas area who insists that he had always spelt the dish Pad See Lew and he is from Thailand.  It is interesting to note that he mentioned the “L’ is silent so the pronunciation is the same as Pad See Ew.

Comment: @JW. LOL! Yeah, and his name is Lou... j/k

Comment: Well, since the dish is *actually* spelled ผัดซีอิ๊ว, transliterations can be fairly creative.

Comment: Ah, modern Roman typography. Why does capital "I/i" have to look like small "L/l" in so many non-serif fonts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are both the same dish and can go by various spellings as noted in the OP.

Answer (score 2):

There is no Pad See Lew. Pad See Ew means to fry with soy sauce. In Thailand this menu is typically cook with flat rice noodle, fry with kale, egg and soy sauce.

I agree that Pad See Lew is a typo error. When I type into google in redirects me to Pad See Ew.

[image: pad see ew]
Credit : [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad_see_ew)

Comment: I don’t think it is a typo.  I updated the OP because I have since found other spellings of this dish.  I do believe this is all the same dish that is being discussed here. Thx.

Comment: I appreciate the picture btw because that is what the dish looks like.